# calculating bootstrap resampling for grouped variables

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, rsample

I have the following dataset to calculate standardized effect size for **Soil_N and Soil_P** for which I used the code below for each replicate.

```
  df <- tibble(
  Soilwater = rep(rep(c("optimal", "reduced"), each = 5), times = 2),
  Diversity = rep(c("high", "low"), each = 10),
  Soil_N = c(50, 45, 49, 48, 49, 69, 68, 69, 70, 67, 79, 78, 79, NA_integer_, 77, 89, 89, 87, 88, 89), 
  Soil_P = c(2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 8, 8, 9, 7, 6, 11, 12, 11, NA_integer_, 10, 18, 18, 17, 21, 19),
  Replicate = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

As value of **one replicate from both Soil_N and Soil_P is missing**, I would like to calculate the value of remaining 4 replicates to create a value for the missing replicate as per code below.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
 pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Diversity, Replicate),
 names_from = Soilwater,
 values_from = c(Soil_N, Soil_P) %>%
 mutate(across(c(optimal, reduced), ~ replace_na(.x, mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE))), 
  ES_N = (Soil_N_optimal - Soil_N_reduced) / (Soil_N_optimal + Soil_N_reduced), 
  ES_P = (Soil_P_optimal - Soil_P_reduced) / (Soil_P_optimal + Soil_P_reduced))%>% 
  group_by(Diversity)
```

I am sure that this code requires to replace the mean value for Soil_N and Soil_P separately in their respective column but I don't know how.
Followed by this, I am willing to calculate the bootstrap sample from the grouped replicates, grouped by each Diversity with 1000 iterations **(meaning that **each ES calculation goes for 1000 times using 5 replicates** using the formula ES = (optimal-reduced)/(optimal+reduced))**. This should be done for both Soil_N and Soil_P.

For bootstrap, I am using the code

```
df_bs<- bootstraps(df, times = 1000, strata = "Diversity") %>%
mutate(means = map(splits, function(x) {
 as.data.frame(x) %>%
  group_by(Diversity) %>%
  summarise(meanN = mean(ES_N), 
  meanP = mean(ES_P))
  })) %>%
  unnest(means)
```

This output from here, I would `pivot_longer` as following to make a graph in ggplot2.

```
 df_final<- df_bs%>%
 select(meanN, meanP)%>%
 pivot_longer(!Diversity, 
           names_to = "variables", 
           values_to = "ES")
 df_final
```

Your help is highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean to bootstrap sample from the grouped replicates, grouped by each `Diversity` category? `bootstraps` takes the whole dataframe as an argument to sample from. To borrow the code from [the examples here](https://rsample.tidymodels.org/reference/bootstraps.html), you could sample 5 random replicates from each Diversity category (with replacement) and for each bootstrap resampling extract the means of each category:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rsample)

df <- tibble(
  Soilwater = rep(rep(c("optimal", "reduced"), each = 5), times = 2),
  Diversity = rep(c("high", "low"), each = 10),
  Soil_N = c(50, 45, 49, 48, 49, 69, 68, 69, 70, 67, 79, 78, 79, NA_integer_, 77, 89, 89, 87, 88, 89),
  Replicate = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
)


df_stand <- df %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(Diversity, Replicate),
    names_from = Soilwater,
    values_from = Soil_N
  ) %>%
  mutate(across(c(optimal, reduced), ~ replace_na(.x, mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE))),
    ES = (optimal - reduced) / (optimal + reduced)
  )


bootstraps(df_stand, times = 50, strata = "Diversity") %>%
  mutate(means = map(splits, function(x) {
    as.data.frame(x) %>%
      group_by(Diversity) %>%
      summarise(mean = mean(ES))
  })) %>%
  unnest(means)


#> # A tibble: 100 x 4
#>    splits         id          Diversity    mean
#>    <list>         <chr>       <chr>       <dbl>
#>  1 <split [10/3]> Bootstrap01 high      -0.165 
#>  2 <split [10/3]> Bootstrap01 low       -0.0868
#>  3 <split [10/3]> Bootstrap02 high      -0.173 
#>  4 <split [10/3]> Bootstrap02 low       -0.0906
#>  5 <split [10/4]> Bootstrap03 high      -0.167 
#>  6 <split [10/4]> Bootstrap03 low       -0.103 
#>  7 <split [10/3]> Bootstrap04 high      -0.184 
#>  8 <split [10/3]> Bootstrap04 low       -0.0881
#>  9 <split [10/4]> Bootstrap05 high      -0.159 
#> 10 <split [10/4]> Bootstrap05 low       -0.0633
#> # ... with 90 more rows
```

## Edit

Your solution is almost there. With the new column of `Soil_P` added in, your `across` function needs to select all the new columns after the pivot. You can use `across(starts_with("Soil"))` to get all the right ones:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rsample)

df <- tibble(
  Soilwater = rep(rep(c("optimal", "reduced"), each = 5), times = 2),
  Diversity = rep(c("high", "low"), each = 10),
  Soil_N = c(50, 45, 49, 48, 49, 69, 68, 69, 70, 67, 79, 78, 79, NA_integer_, 77, 89, 89, 87, 88, 89), 
  Soil_P = c(2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 8, 8, 9, 7, 6, 11, 12, 11, NA_integer_, 10, 18, 18, 17, 21, 19),
  Replicate = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5))



df_stand <- df %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(Diversity, Replicate),
    names_from = Soilwater,
    values_from = c(Soil_N, Soil_P)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    across(starts_with("Soil"), ~ replace_na(.x, mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE))),
    ES_N = (Soil_N_optimal - Soil_N_reduced) / (Soil_N_optimal + Soil_N_reduced),
    ES_P = (Soil_P_optimal - Soil_P_reduced) / (Soil_P_optimal + Soil_P_reduced)
  )


df_bs <- bootstraps(df_stand, times = 1000, strata = 'Diversity') %>%
  mutate(means = map(splits, function(x) {
    as.data.frame(x) %>%
      group_by(Diversity) %>%
      summarise(meanN = mean(ES_N),
                meanP = mean(ES_P))
  })) %>%
  unnest(means)

df_final <- df_bs %>% 
  select(Diversity, meanN, meanP) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Diversity,
               names_to = "variables", 
               values_to = "ES")

df_final

#> # A tibble: 4,000 x 3
#>    Diversity variables      ES
#>    <chr>     <chr>       <dbl>
#>  1 high      meanN     -0.177 
#>  2 high      meanP     -0.48  
#>  3 low       meanN     -0.0611
#>  4 low       meanP     -0.241 
#>  5 high      meanN     -0.164 
#>  6 high      meanP     -0.68  
#>  7 low       meanN     -0.0787
#>  8 low       meanP     -0.299 
#>  9 high      meanN     -0.187 
#> 10 high      meanP     -0.44  
#> # ... with 3,990 more rows
```

This outputs the dataframe with the mean values of each of the 1,000 bootstrap samples for each value of `Diversity`. And then it's just a case of plotting as needed :).

<sup>Created on 2022-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Then I would like to feed this into bootstrap function for **two** response variables.

Comment: Can you put your updated code (with the solutions you've tried) into your question to make it clearer? `Soil_P` isn't in your original question so I don't know how to use it! I'm also not quite clear what your output should be. Are `Soil_N` and `Soil_P` paired measurements for each replicate? i.e. should they be in rows sampled together by bootstrap or sampled separately?

Comment: done! looking forward to hear back.

Comment: Hope edited version helps answer the question!

Comment: Thank you very much! It was great to get your help! One question still remains though it what to do when I have to mutate multiple variables with NAs that have different starting and ending names. For ex., for Soil_N and Soil_P, I can use the function `starts_with` but imagine if I have **UWE, LDMC, WWC**, and so on to mutate across, along with Soil_N and Soil_P? Any easy solution exists?

Comment: Hi Amit, [there's quite a few ways to select variables](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html) in across! If they are all together in your dataset you could do first:last as in `Soil_N:WWC` for example. Or you could de-select columns you don't want to run the `replace_na` function on using `across(!c(Diversity, Replicate)...`. Or you could *first* `group_by(Diversity, Replicate)` and then just do `across(everything()...` (which misses out grouping variables. Hope this helps!